# How do I retrieve the domain from a URL?

Tags: go

In Go, how can I extract only the domain name from a URL string?

Before:

```
https://www.example.com/some-random-url
www.example.com/some-random-url
example.com/some-random-url
www.example.com
subdomain.example.com
```

After:

```
example.com
```

Also, I'm limited to using the Golang standard library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think since your examples has incorrect URLs as well, you need to use Regular Expresssion to extract the domain in the URL. Please find the sample code below to get the domain for the examples you shared:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "regexp"
)

// Main function
func main() {

    // Finding regexp from the given string
    // Using FindString() method
    m := regexp.MustCompile(`\.?([^.]*.com)`)

    fmt.Println(m.FindStringSubmatch("https://www.example.com/some-random-url")[1])
    fmt.Println(m.FindStringSubmatch("www.example.com/some-random-url")[1])
    fmt.Println(m.FindStringSubmatch("example.com/some-random-url")[1])
    fmt.Println(m.FindStringSubmatch("www.example.com")[1])
    fmt.Println(m.FindStringSubmatch("subdomain.example.com")[1])

}
```

Ideally, this covers all the cases (including incorrectly formed URLs). You can easily update RegEx if there is any URL that doesn't get parsed correctly.

Go Playground link for the above: [here](https://play.golang.org/p/-JoaT32QuMg).

Comment: Can you accept the answer? so that others don't spend time on this question :)

Answer (score 1):

I've finally figured it out.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "net/url"
    "strings"
)

func main() {
    url, err := url.Parse("https://www.example.com")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    parts := strings.Split(url.Hostname(), ".")
    domain := parts[len(parts)-2] + "." + parts[len(parts)-1]
    fmt.Println(domain)
}
```

`example.com`

If the domain is something like `subdomain.example.com` than it will give you a panic.

https://play.golang.org/p/Li0PviAr2jU

Comment: panics with `subdomain.example.com`

Comment: Yeah, Do u know any fix to this?

Comment: put your example inputs correctly and describe what you want exactly from them

Comment: It panics for all the other examples. I have added regex based solution above.

Comment: The number of dots doesn't mean anything (consider bbc.co.uk). If you want to strip subdomains reliably you have to use something like [the publicsuffix package](https://pkg.go.dev/golang.org/x/net/publicsuffix).

Comment: I support this @Peter

Answer (score 1):

I think this can be helpful

```
package main

import (
"fmt"
"log"
"net/url"
"strings"
)
func main() {
    strArray := []string{
    "www.google.co.in",
    "https://google.in",
    "instagram.com",
    "nymag.com",
    "http://www.example.com/?airport=approval&box=brother",
    "https://www.example.com/babies.php#birds",
    "http://example.org/bear",
    "www.google.co.in",
    "google.com",
    "https://www.bbb.org/search/business-review-form/",
    "https://www.localvisibilitysystem.com/2015/08/19/how-to-use-meetup-sponsorships-for-local-marketing-and-seo-dave-oremlands-tips/",
    "http://www.example.com/boat/advertisement?actor=bat#boundary",
    "https://www.example.com/",
    "https://www.google.com",
    "https://www.example.com/army/approval.htm?basket=bottle",
    "http://example.com/board.aspx?afternoon=appliance&angle=ball",
    "http://www.example.com/",
    "http://example.com/",
    "http://www.example.com/",
    "livejournal.com",
    "delicious.com",
    "illinois.edu",
    "instagram.com",
    "nymag.com",
    "altervista.org",
    "t.co",
    "reddit.com",
    "tinyurl.com",
}
var hostname string
var temp []string
for i := 0; i < len(strArray); i++ {
    url, err := url.Parse(strArray[i])
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    var urlstr string = url.String()
```

here prefix and host name will be filtered

```
    if strings.HasPrefix(urlstr, "https") {
        hostname = strings.TrimPrefix(urlstr, "https://")
    } else if strings.HasPrefix(urlstr, "http") {
        hostname = strings.TrimPrefix(urlstr, "http://")
    } else {
        hostname = urlstr
    }

    if strings.HasPrefix(hostname, "www") {
        hostname = strings.TrimPrefix(hostname, "www.")
    }
    if strings.Contains(hostname, "/") {
        temp = strings.Split(hostname, "/")
        fmt.Println(temp[0])
    } else {
        fmt.Println(hostname)
    }

}
}
```

output:

```
 google.co.in
 google.in
 instagram.com
 nymag.com
 example.com
 example.com
 example.org
 google.co.in
 google.com
 bbb.org
 localvisibilitysystem.com
 example.com
 example.com
 google.com
 example.com
 example.com
 example.com
 example.com
 example.com
 livejournal.com
 delicious.com
 illinois.edu
 instagram.com
 nymag.com
 altervista.org
 t.co
 reddit.com
 tinyurl.com
```

this will  give you required Domain from any url
Go Playground link for the above:
https://go.dev/play/p/vfCOAnTNqh8

Answer (score 0):

This solution

```golang
func extractDomain(urlLikeString string) string {

    urlLikeString = strings.TrimSpace(urlLikeString)

    if regexp.MustCompile(`^https?`).MatchString(urlLikeString) {
        read, _ := url.Parse(urlLikeString)
        urlLikeString = read.Host
    }

    if regexp.MustCompile(`^www\.`).MatchString(urlLikeString) {
        urlLikeString = regexp.MustCompile(`^www\.`).ReplaceAllString(urlLikeString, "")
    }

    return regexp.MustCompile(`([a-z0-9\-]+\.)+[a-z0-9\-]+`).FindString(urlLikeString)
}
```

will turn this

```json
"   ",
"aaa",
"not domain",
"ca.mail.google.com",
"google.com",
" google.com ",
" www.google.com/a/example.com",
"www.google.com/f/example.com",
"google.com/f/example.com",
"http://google.com/f/abc.com",
"http://google.com/f/?wow=xyz.com",
"http://google.com/f/?wow=www.xyz.com",
"http://www.google.com/f/abc.com",
"https://www.google.com/f/abc.com",
"https://mail.google.com/f/abc.com",
"https://123.google.com/f/abc.com",
"https://xn-ddf3.google.com/f/abc.com",
```

into this

```json
[empty string]
[empty string]
[empty string]
ca.mail.google.com
google.com
google.com
google.com
google.com
google.com
google.com
google.com
google.com
google.com
google.com
mail.google.com
123.google.com
xn-ddf3.google.com
```

"net/url" method `url.Parse` won't handle domain-like string, like:  `bla bla google.com`.